# JAVA - Add Objects to JSON from a join SQL query

Tags: java, mysql, json

I hope the title is well set...

I have an existing Java application (i cannot change all the application) which simply exposes db tables as JSON using gson library.

My problem is how to create a Json not only with the simple fields of the DB but with the linked Objects.

I have a table in this way

```
| objectid | plantid | other_fields |
```

Now the existing gson gives me simply the `plantid` as an integer, but i have a `plants` table

```
| plantid | plantname | other_fields |
```

I would like to have the gson with the Plant Object, not simply the *plantid*

This is how the application maps the Sql query to the Model

```
public ArrayList<ObjectsEntity> getObject(String objectId){
        ArrayList<ObjectsEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            Connection connLocal = connFactLocal.getConnection();
            String query = "select * from OBJECTS o left join PLANTS p on o.PLANTID = p.PLANTID "
                    + "left join OBJECTTYPES ot on o.OBJECTTYPEID = ot.OBJECTTYPEID";
            Statement stmt = connLocal.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                ObjectsEntity oe = new ObjectsEntity();
                oe.setOBJECTID(rs.getInt("OBJECTID"));
                oe.setPLANTID(rs.getInt("PLANTID"));
                oe.setOBJECTNAME(rs.getString("OBJECTNAME"));
                oe.setOBJECTTYPEID(rs.getInt("OBJECTTYPEID"));
                oe.setDESCRIPTION(rs.getString("DESCRIPTION"));
                oe.setISMONITORED(rs.getBoolean("ISMONITORED"));
                oe.setGROUP(rs.getString("GROUP"));
                list.add(oe);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            logger.error("SQL Error:",e);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

ObjectsEntity.java is a simple mapper with the DB table with getters and setters
I've tried to change this mapper updating

```
int PLANTID
```

with

```
Plants plant
```

But then i don't know how to set the Plants from the ResultSet of the query... any idea?

Comment: Since you already have an object to store your data you just need to change `oe.setPLANTID(rs.getInt("PLANTID"));` for `Plants plants = new Plants(); plants.setId(rs.getInt("PLANTID")); plants.setOtherFields(....)....; oe.setPlants(plants);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to populate Plants object using data from resultset and set that on ObjectsEntity . Using ObjectMapper you can convert ObjectsEntity to JSON String

```
    while (rs.next()) {
                    ObjectsEntity oe = new ObjectsEntity();
                    oe.setOBJECTID(rs.getInt("OBJECTID"));
                    Plants plants = new Plants();
                    plants.setId(rs.getInt("PLANTID"));
                      //Set other fields.
                    oe.setPLANTS(plants);
                    oe.setOBJECTNAME(rs.getString("OBJECTNAME"));
                    oe.setOBJECTTYPEID(rs.getInt("OBJECTTYPEID"));
                    oe.setDESCRIPTION(rs.getString("DESCRIPTION"));
                    oe.setISMONITORED(rs.getBoolean("ISMONITORED"));
                    oe.setGROUP(rs.getString("GROUP"));
                    list.add(oe);
                }
```

Comment: Which ObjectMapper? Jackson? Are you expecting OP to know what class you meant?

Comment: Jackson ObjectMapper. Which will help you to convert java object to JSON string. You need to use the @JsonProperty annotations on ObjectsEntity Bean

Comment: I know Jackon very well,but that what not point of my comment (and you don;t necessary need annotations).

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?
The question is how to set plants using ResultSet

Comment: Thanks @MayurB, it works also with Gson library, don't need to use Jackson

Answer (score 0):

While it is perfectly possible to do all this mapping and plumbing manually with JDBC directly, using third parties might be much simpler here? 2 of the most popular third party libraries for SQL in Java are [jOOQ](https://jooq.org) and [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org)

#### A jOOQ solution

With jOOQ, you can use [nested records](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/nested-records/) along with [ad-hoc converters](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/) for type safe mapping of query results to your target data structures, e.g.:

```java
List<ObjectEntity> result =
ctx.select(
        OBJECTS.OBJECTID, 
        row(
            OBJECTS.plant().PLANTID,
            OBJECTS.plant().PLANTNAME
        ).mapping(Plant::new))
   .from(OBJECTS)
   .fetch(mapping(ObjectEntity::new));
```

Disclaimer, I work for the company behind jOOQ

#### A Hibernate solution

In Hibernate/JPA, you'd be designing your objects as entities, such as:

```java
@Entity
class Plant {
    // Most annotations omitted for brevity
    int plantid;
    String plantname;
}
@Entity
class Object {
    int objectid;
    @ManyToOne(...)
    Plant plant;
}
```

You can now fetch your entities using JPQL, without specifying the nesting explicitly.